# What shebang should I use to consistently point to python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shebang

I have a script which uses the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`. It works great on machines where Python 3 is the only version available, but on the machines which have both Python 2 and Python 3, it runs the script with Python 2.

If I modify the shebang to be `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, it would work on the machines with Python 2 and Python 3, but on the machines which have only Python 3, it would fail with “No such file or directory” error.

One solution is to create an alias `alias python=python3`.

Are there other solutions to have a same shebang working uniformly on every machine?

Comment: The `alias` won't work (aliases aren't checked by `env`). Even machines that install only Python 3 *should* install it as both `python` and `python3`; if you have root, you can always make a symlink if the OS fails to provide it: `cd /path/where/python/is/found; sudo ln -s python python3`. Basically, your shebang is the correct and canonical shebang, but sometimes the OS is wrong, and must be taught to be right.

Comment: Typically when installing Python you will get `python`, `python<major>` and `python<major>.<minor>`, if not occupied already.

Comment: In that case where its compatible with both, isn't it fine to omit the shebang line so the python launcher will just find the latest version available?

Comment: “but on the machines which have only Python 3, it would fail with “No such file or directory” error” — Does it? Most Python3 installations should have a `python3` binary in the PATH, even when python2 isn’t installed, precisely to alleviate the pains of finding it.

Comment: @Peter If you remove the shebang completely, the os won't necessarily know it is a python script.  I don't know if bash would use the file extension as an indicator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no universally working way of doing this that would work across any and all up front unknown Linux hosts and you are largely left at the mercy of distro maintainers and local host configuration.

`alias` won't help, because interpreter specified by `#!` handled by the kernel and `/usr/bin/env` it will exec in this case does not know about aliases of your shell.

When using `env`, you could make sure that the name following `env` is first found and means what you want it to mean by:

- making sure all hosts are setup the same way in that respect (expected packaged are installed or at least symlinks are created)
- having user specific construct for execution of your script, such as:

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/bin
  ln -s /usr/bin/python /tmp/bin/python3
  PATH="/tmp/bin:${PATH}" ./myscript.py
  ```

But none of this is really great and ultimately what you've asked for.

Your interpreter (this is harder than it may sound though, interpreter resolution code is quite simple; where to put it, how to call it for kernel to find and use it) could also be a simple shell script that tries to figure it out that you pack with your python code, but any option you look at isn't really great I am afraid.

There is a [PEP-394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) for that which suggested / expected on U*X-like system:

- you get `python` for python2
- and `python3` for python3

But it recognizes this has never been entirely consistently applied... and also not as useful in 2020:

> However, these recommendations implicitly assumed that Python 2 would always be available. As Python 2 is nearing its end of life in 2020 (PEP 373, PEP 404), distributions are making Python 2 optional or removing it entirely. This means either removing the python command or switching it to invoke Python 3. Some distributors also decided that their users were better served by ignoring the PEP's original recommendations, and provided system administrators with the freedom to configure their systems based on the needs of their particular environment.

TL;DR unfortunately there is no way that universally works and compensates for decisions of various distro and even individual host maintainers. :(

I would most likely opt to stick with `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (which has so far been the recommended naming) and add a `README` that explains the prerequisites and how to setup the host just to be sure.

---

For the sake of completeness I should add, the PEP does make a recommendation in this regard: setup and use virtual environment or use a (third party) environment manager. However the way I read the question: "Portable interpreter specification that does not make any assumptions about nor poses any (additional) requirements to target host configuration", this would then not fit the bill and would not mean a substantial improvement over saying: make sure you have `python3` executable in the search path and create a symlink if not.

Comment: This answer is a lot more pessimistic than warranted. In reality, virtually all properly configured machines will have `python3` in PATH. And the users of the tiny minority that don’t will probably already be aware of the issue. — That said, a proper setuptools installation takes care of that anyway, by hard-coding the correct interpreter path at installation time.

Comment: I would generally agree (and I've amended the answer slightly) . Unfortunately the question hints at an environment where this actually is an issue. I also suspect as deployments of Python 2 gradually disappear, this may for a while get worse before it gets better.

Comment: BTW. I personally wish and hope for distros to keep the `python3` name indefinitely, because it's been used like that for quite a while and there are many scripts relying on its presence meaning dropping this name as access to the interpreter would generate hassle while there does not seem to be any substantial benefit justifying breaking with the past.

Comment: **For Windows users:** `#!/usr/bin/env python3` **does not** work. Use `#!/usr/bin/env python` if you want to be Linux compatible, or just leave it out if not.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I've settled on for now, though I'm still trying to write my code such that it can work with Python 2 in the cases where that's necessary. You can modify this to your needs if you have a few known paths, for instance (it doesn't all need to be on one line):

```
#!/bin/bash
_='''' # Prefer python3 if it exists
command -v python3 &> /dev/null && exec python3 $0 "$@" || exec python $0 "$@"
'''
# Python code here
print ("Hello")
```

That's based on an example from this page about hybrid scripts: https://gist.github.com/andyneff/fafba17b748bba6d7cd5

The script is initially loaded in bash, which sees the first line beginning with `_=''''`, which is interpreted by bash as setting the variable `_` to two null strings (`''`) in a row.

The second line uses `command -v python3` to try and determine if `python3` is in the path or defined as an alias, with stdout and stderr redirected to the null device. If it has a successful return code, then `exec python3 $0 "$@"` is run, where `$0` is the name of the script and `"$@"` expands to the list of arguments. If it fails, the equivalent `python` command is run.

Since the command is `exec`'d, the python3/python command replaces the current bash process, and bash never sees the following lines.

When Python reads the file, it sees `_=''''` and interprets it as the beginning of a `'''...'''` multi-line triple-quoted string, even though it begins with four apostrophes rather than just three, so the script ends up with a harmless extra `_` variable set.

Answer (score 2):

**`#!/usr/bin/env python3` is the most correct general solution.** On systems where Python 3 is installed, *this should work*, regardless of whether Python 2 is installed or not.

That said, there’s still no guarantee that the *right* version of Python 3 is installed, and hard-coding, say, `python3.7` isn’t viable since most users won’t have several versions installed.

Luckily there’s a better solution: **If you distribute your application as a Python package** with [Setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) and specify `entry_points` for your binary/binaries, the installation process will pick the correct interpreter and hard-code its path into your application scripts. This will work regardless of environment, as long as the installer (e.g. `pip`) can find Python at all.

As a very simple example, say your project `example` has the following folder structure:

```
example
├── example
│   ╰── __init__.py
├── pyproject.toml
╰── setup.cfg
```

And let’s assume your `__init__.py` has a function `main` that we want to use as an entry point for an executable script.

Then [`pyproject.toml`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/#build-system-table) would look like this:<sup>1</sup>

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
```

And `setup.cfg` looks as follows:<sup>1,2</sup>

```
[metadata]
name = example
version = 0.0.1

[options]
packages = find:

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    example-bin = example:main
```

Now you can build your project using e.g. `pip3 bdist path-to-project`, which will generate the Wheel installation bundle. When you install that (either after uploading it to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) or locally (via `pip3 install wheel-filename.whl`), pip3 will install the binary `example-bin`.

`example-bin` will launch your package’s entry point function, and will work regardless of what the Python 3 binary is called on your system, because `pip3 install …` creates this file with an absolute path in the shebang line. For example, on my system the first line of that file is

```sh
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Rather than use `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg`, the same works using the legacy `setup.py` file — but using the above is simpler.

<sup>2</sup> Note that, at the time of writing, there’s a typo in the Setuptools quickstart: instead of `[entry_point]`, it should read `[entry_points]`.

Comment: **Important for Windows users:** `#!/usr/bin/env python3` **does not** work. Use `#!/usr/bin/env python` if you want to be Linux compatible, or just leave it out if not.

Comment: @Rsge Using `python` instead of `python3` is explicitly not recommended since there are *still* many legacy systems where this points to Python 2 (hence this question). Likewise, “leave it out” is flat-out *not* a solution because that *does not work* on POSIX systems! The best solution is, and remains, to package and install the script properly using setuptools. That said, contrary to your comment the shebang line *does* work on Windows (MinGW, Git Bash, WSL or whatever you’re using) if Python has been set up properly. And if it hasn’t, a symlink for python3 can be easily added.

Comment: I'm talking explicitly about **Windows**, meaning `python.exe` started by `py.exe` via double clicking on a `.py` file. In that case, using `python3` there positively *does not* work (on my system, with only Python 3.12 installed). What *does* work is `env` with just `python` as I said or `#!/usr/bin/python3`. The problem with the latter being the hardcoded path for Linux. But maybe that is still the better choice if you run the risk of the Linux system in question still running Python 2.

Comment: @Rsge I was also talking about Windows, though not about double-clicking on a file but rather launching it via the command line. However, [`py.exe` explicitly supports `/usr/bin/env python3`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines). If this doesn’t work for you it means no `python3` is in your `%PATH%` variable. And, as mentioned in my previous comment, you can fix that by creating an appropriate shortcut or by defining the environment variable `%PYLAUNCHER_NO_SEARCH_PATH%`. If that doesn’t work, your Python setup is screwed up or you don’t have Python 3 installed.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if there was some error in my system, so I set up a clean Windows 10 VM and installed Python 3.12.1, checking "Add python.exe to PATH" during install, installing for all users and disabling path length limit. Then I wrote a `test.py` with just the shebang and an `input("Test")`. Double-clicking this, it just opened and closed again. In Powershell, doing `.\test.py` or `py .\test.py` exits `Python could not be found ...`, doing `python .\test.py` works as expected. Changing `python3` to just `python` in the shebang, all four approaches work as expected. So, same problem as OP.

Comment: "“leave it out” is flat-out not a solution because that does not work on POSIX systems!"
Yes, it is, for scripts already written with use on Windows in mind. You don't need compatibility for those. An edge case for most, probably, I'll admit, but possible.