# Is it possible to construct a shebang that works for both Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, shebang

I need to write a Python script that's compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3, can be called directly from a shell (meaning it has a shebang), and can run on systems that have either Python version installed, but possibly not both.

Normally I can write a shebang for Python 2 like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and for Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

But both of these will fail if their corresponding Python version is not installed, since as far as I'm aware, systems that have Python 3 but not Python 2 do not alias or symlink `python` to `python3`. (Do correct me if I'm wrong.)

So is there a way to write a Python script with a shebang that will execute the script using either Python 2 or Python 3 so long as one of them is installed?

<del>This is mainly intended to solve the removal of Python 2 from upcoming releases of macOS,</del> *(Note: I originally wrote that under the mistaken understanding that Python 2 would be replaced with Python 3 in macOS, but in reality Apple is removing Python completely.)* but can apply to Linux as well.

Comment: the first shebang calls the default Python, which can be either 2 or 3. It is unlikely that a system would have a specific version installed but won't have a default Python alias set up. So, TLDR: the first shebang is what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you just detect the presence or absence of Python with a shell script and invoke the correct interpreter depending on what the shell script detects?

Comment: How will you be installing your script in the first place? Usually you don't write the shebang yourself, the installer writes it when installing your code and it associates with whatever Python runtime was used to install the package.

Comment: Systems with only Python 3 typically install it under the `python` name. That's the distributor's choice, but I see it more often than not.

Comment: @AlexW I considered doing that, but if possible I'd prefer to keep the script as a single file that can still be imported into python as well as run directly as a standalone script. A correct shebang will accomplish that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Realistically I would just specify `python3` and make that a prerequisite.

However, it's technically possible to trick a Python file into being its own shell script wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
''':'
for name in python3 python2 python
do
    type "$name" > /dev/null 2>&1 && exec "$name" "$0" "$@"
done
echo >&2 "Please install python"
exit 1
':'''

print("Hello from Python")
```

Comment: this is brilliant! You should mention that `exec` replaces the current shell script.

Comment: I was wondering if something like this was possible! I'm also curious what meaning `''':'` and `':'''` have, and how it works out to not affect the intervening shell script.

Comment: Surely you need to forward the arguments too?

Comment: @BriBri: for the shell, `''':'` is just `:` (look it up as "colon command")

Comment: the only thing I wonder is how much shell-agnostic that `echo >&2 "..."` is

Comment: I think it should be `... && exec "$name" "$0" "$@"`

Comment: @WalterTross It's standard POSIX if that's what you mean

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks, I thought that `echo "..." >&2` was more standard

Comment: This may not technically be just a shebang, but it does exactly what I need, and even better I can set it up to prioritize python3 over python2

Answer (score 1):

This seems to allow choosing python 3 over python 2, and will use either if found. [Snagged from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69412632/26510), and allows you to deal with the situation where some people only have python 2 installed on their machine, and some only have python 3

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
_='''' # Prefer python3 if it exists
command -v python3 &> /dev/null && exec python3 $0 "$@" || exec python $0 "$@"
'''
# Python code here
print ("Hello")
```